# Add up/down button on jQuery scroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

HTML:

```
<div id="scrooly" class="span7">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet quam et orci dictum sagittis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi sed dictum nibh. Nullam felis est, feugiat a ullamcorper sed, iaculis ut ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam in sapien magna, in feugiat velit. Quisque tellus est, ultricies a euismod sed, consectetur et libero. Quisque ac libero in elit suscipit semper. Cras eget metus quis turpis ultrices aliquam sed at enim. Integer ullamcorper odio consequat nunc egestas tempus. Cras eget orci elit, ac eleifend nunc. Phasellus tincidunt nibh arcu. Donec laoreet ornare nisl, sit amet rutrum sem mollis sed.
    </p>
    <img src="assets/img/photo01.jpg" />
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet quam et orci dictum sagittis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi sed dictum nibh. Nullam felis est, feugiat a ullamcorper sed, iaculis ut ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam in sapien magna, in feugiat velit. Quisque tellus est, ultricies a euismod sed, consectetur et libero. Quisque ac libero in elit suscipit semper. Cras eget metus quis turpis ultrices aliquam sed at enim. Integer ullamcorper odio consequat nunc egestas tempus. Cras eget orci elit, ac eleifend nunc. Phasellus tincidunt nibh arcu. Donec laoreet ornare nisl, sit amet rutrum sem mollis sed.
    </p>
</div>
```

And my all structure:

http://jsfiddle.net/2FcZN/

It's working good but I want, UP and DOWN button on my scrollbar. How can I do this?

Comment: you can over-ride the buttons on default scroll, with positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

Create 2 buttons:

```
<button id='upClick'>Go Up</button>
<button id='downClick'>Go Down</button>
```

jQuery:

```
var scrolled = 0;
$("#downClick").on("click", function() {
    scrolled = scrolled + $("#scrooly").scrollHeight; //Edit <<
    $("#scrooly").animate({
        scrollTop: scrolled
    });
});


$("#upClick").on("click", function() {
    scrolled = scrolled - $("#scrooly").scrollHeight; //Edit <<

    $("#scrooly").animate({
        scrollTop: scrolled
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2FcZN/3/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it works but when click up or down button, crashed scroll function. Did you see that?

Comment: This is probably because I target the wrong element. Your are doing something with the height of your page/div.. If you scroll down and then up, it works.. You should check what element you should target. I updated my code so it will always scroll to the bottom of the element. I'm not sure what you are doing with your custom scrollbars. You can also target the body (not working in jsfiddle).

Answer (score -1):

try setting the bottom with a value set to 24px, as the height of the footer

Comment: how is that even related